# wpf IsEnabled button binding, only works once....already have PropertyChange notification

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, binding

here is my xaml:

```
<Button 
 x:Name="StartBtn" 
 Content="Start"
 Command="{Binding StartProcess}"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Height="23" 
 Margin="241,181,0,0" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Width="57" 
 Grid.Column="1" 
 IsEnabled="{Binding IsStartButtonEnabled}"/>
```

here is my property:

```
 private bool _isStartButtonEnabled;
        public bool IsStartButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return _isStartButtonEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isStartButtonEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsStartButtonEnabled");
            }
        }
```

it works with whatever i set it to on startup, but when i manipulate the bool later in the code, the change is not reflected in the WPF. I do have the data context set correctly as other bindings all function perfectly.

Also when I manipulate the Bool in the code I am using the property and not the private field.

```
private void OnStartProcess()
        {
            IsStartButtonEnabled = false;
            //stuff
        }
```

Comment: I am assuming you are changing the property value not the private field value?

Comment: correct. Thats what i do for all my bindings and they all work fine (except this one)

Comment: I just run it and it works fine. How do you know that the binding is correct? There are a couple of things you can check one being the output window to look for error 40, and other is to set a break point on the getter of your property to see whether the xaml actually reads from it.

Comment: Your Button might be contained inside some other control and that control's IsEnabled property overtaking it.

Answer (score 0):

It is working, make sure you are setting the public property in your code and not the private field:

```
   public RelayCommand StartProcess
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(Execute);
        }
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        IsStartButtonEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: yea thats what im doing

Comment: private void OnStartProcess()
        {
            IsStartButtonEnabled = false;